# Проблемы миграции LibGDX 1.3.1 -> 1.4.1 на IOS.

Tags: libgdx, ios

Если использовать LibGDX 1.3.1, то в IOS8 возникает баг: при повороте некорректно определяются ширина и высота экрана, и из-за этого отображение в альбомной (и в портретной, возможно, тоже) ориентации отображается на 2/3-х экрана.

Лечится это, вроде бы, обновлением LibGDX до версии 1.4.1. Код, напомню, написан для 1.3.1, и видимо, там что-то нужно доделать, но непонятно, что именно.

Обновление проводил согласно их документам   https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/CHANGES, (c), но в итоге получил программу, никак не реагирующую ни на какие нажатия и таскания, причем не реагирует и на IOS7, и на IOS8.

Полагаю, что-то нужно сделать по-другому при инициализации.

Вопрос такой: кто обновлял libGDX с 1.3.1 до 1.4.1 или 1.4.2, что вы делали, чтобы все заработало?

P.S. Апгрейдил так: в build.gradle прописал

```
    ...
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
            classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha-04'(было 1.0.0-alpha-01)
    }
    ...

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'xxx'
        gdxVersion = '1.4.2-SNAPSHOT'(было 1.3.1)
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-alpha-04'(1.0.0-alpha-01)
...
}
```

Переименовывал:

```
titleLabel.setEllipse(true) стало titleLabel.setEllipsis(true);
```

в Actor

```
this.getOriginY() стало this.getY(Align.bottom)
```

в Stage

```
cancelTouchFocus(flickScrollListener, this) стало cancelTouchFocusExcept(flickScrollListener, this);
```

Вроде бы все...